# Splitting DataFrame columns into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file containing 2 columns filled with data

```
Column_1 | Column_2
Data_1   | Data_1
Data_2   | Data_2
Data_3   | Data_3
Data_4   | Data_4
.
.
.
```

The thing is that I want to reorganize the number of rows so that after 30 rows, two new columns will be created and fit the rest of the 30 other rows into those two new columns so that will be like this:

```
Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4
Data_1   | Data_1   | Data_31  | Data_31
Data_2   | Data_2   | Data_32  | Data_32
Data_3   | Data_3   | Data_33  | Data_33
Data_4   | Data_4   | Data_34  | Data_34
.
.
.
Data_30   | Data_30 | Data_60  | Data_60
```

The reason is that my workplace waste too much paper to print lists that contains all objects used by the employees, and that we need to make an inventory check every 6 months or so, and to do that, we have to print the relation containing all those items so we can do a check list, and the system they use is not efficient because it also print a bunch of useless columns with data that we simple do not need. I already made a script to clear the data into a CSV, but I now need a way to also make this CSV fit columns to the right so that we could fit as many columns as possible before using another paper to fit more columns to print.

Answer (score 0):

Define two helper columns "group" (`[0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1, ...]`) and "index" (`[0, 1, 2, ..., 0, 1, 2, ...]`) using numpy `divmod` and then unstack appropriately:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({col: [f"Data_{i}" for i in range(1, 61)] 
                         for col in ["column_1", "column_2"]})
len_new = 30

df["group"], df["index"] = np.divmod(np.arange(len(df)), len_new)
df = df.set_index(["group", "index"]).unstack("group").sort_index(axis=1, level=-1)
df.columns = [f"Column_{icol}" for icol in range(1, 1 + len(df.columns))]
df

# Out:
      Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4
index                                    
0       Data_1   Data_1  Data_31  Data_31
1       Data_2   Data_2  Data_32  Data_32
2       Data_3   Data_3  Data_33  Data_33
3       Data_4   Data_4  Data_34  Data_34
4       Data_5   Data_5  Data_35  Data_35
...
```

This will fill up the last two columns with `NaN`s in case the length of df is not a multiple of the number of groups.

---

Solution 2:
Numpy `array_split` and stack:

```
n_groups = 2 
pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(np.array_split(df.values, n_groups)), 
             columns=[f"Column_{i}" for i in range(1, 1 + 2 * n_groups)])
```

Note that this will fail if the length of df is not a multiple of n_groups, since hstack requires equal sizes.